# Simple Python program checking for intersection points

Tags: python-2.7, exception

The aim of the program is to find those points which comes under the intersection of at least 2 circles.(space is a 1000x1000 matrix)

```
n=input()
mat=[[0 for i in range(1005)] for i in range(1005)]
circles=[]

for i in range(n):
    circles.append(map(int,raw_input().split()))

ans=0 
for circle in circles:
    minx=circle[0]-circle[2]
    maxx=circle[0]+circle[2]
    miny=circle[1]-circle[2]
    maxy=circle[1]+circle[2]
    for i in range(minx,maxx+1):
        for j in range(miny,maxy+1):
            if mat[i][j]<=1:
                if ((i-circle[0])**2+(j-circle[1])**2)<=(circle[2]**2):
                    mat[i][j]+=1
                    if mat[i][j]>1:
                        ans+=1
print ans
```

n denoted the number of circle
circles contain circle center and radius in the format [x,y,r] for example let circles = [[3,2,4],[2,5,2]] then it contains two circles centered at (3,2) and (2,5) with radius 4 and 2 respectively.

Is the logic correct?...will it trigger any exceptions??

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: I tried and found nothing...I want to double check

Comment: You may have better luck on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as this site is for solving problems rather than to check code.